# ASP.Net PasswordStrength Control Display Issues in Chrome and Safari

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, safari, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First off, jQuery is not an option at this particular time in this project or I would just utilize that type of password strength option.

Currently I have an Ajax control toolkit control (PasswordStrength) setup to work with a textbox. The control is inside the table row/cell next to the textbox itself in which it validates. It is also setup to be a bar-type indicator that is displayed on the Right side of the textbox through the DisplayPosition property.

The strength meter appears fine in IE, Firefox and Opera ... Right next to the password field textbox and this is great. Now, in Chrome and Safari, the indicator appears at a random place on the page and if you continue typing the indicator actually moves up and down the page randomly, nowhere close to the right side of the password textbox. The indicator is technically correct on the x-axis, meaning it is "beside" the textbox, but the y-axis is sporadic and moves up and down the page, nowhere near the textbox. The behavior is the same in Chrome and Safari.

Any ideas? It's making me a bit nutty as I've tried wrapping divs, positioning, moving the control, adjusting properties etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the textbox and control itself as it is currently setup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Width="150px" runat="server" 
Style="text-align: left" TextMode="Password" </asp:TextBox>

<asp:PasswordStrength ID="PS1" 
          runat="server" 
          TargetControlID="txtPassword" 
          DisplayPosition="RightSide" 
          StrengthIndicatorType="BarIndicator" 
          PreferredPasswordLength="16" 
          MinimumNumericCharacters="1" 
          MinimumSymbolCharacters="1" 
          MinimumLowerCaseCharacters="1" 
          MinimumUpperCaseCharacters="1" 
          RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="false" 
          CalculationWeightings="50;15;15;20" 
          TextStrengthDescriptionStyles="barRed;barYellow;barBlue;barGreen" 
          Enabled="true" 
          BarBorderCssClass="barBorder" 
          BarIndicatorCssClass="barInternal">
</asp:PasswordStrength>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!